# Application_Error and ExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, global-asax, application-error

So I have recently built at **ExceptionFilter** which handles all errors except Api Errors.
The **ExceptionFilter** looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles any exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current context</param>
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {

        // If our exception has been handled, exit the function
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        // If our exception is not an ApiException
        if (!(filterContext.Exception is ApiException))
        {

            // Set our base status code
            var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            // If our exception is an http exception
            if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
            {

                // Cast our exception as an HttpException
                var exception = (HttpException)filterContext.Exception;

                // Get our real status code
                statusCode = exception.GetHttpCode();
            }

            // Set our context result
            var result = CreateActionResult(filterContext, statusCode);

            // Set our handled property to true
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creats an action result from the status code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="statusCode">The status code of the error</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ExceptionContext filterContext, int statusCode)
    {

        // Create our context
        var context = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, filterContext.Controller);
        var statusCodeName = ((HttpStatusCode)statusCode).ToString();

        // Create our route
        var controller = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var action = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controller, action);

        // Create our result
        var view = SelectFirstView(context, string.Format("~/Views/Error/{0}.cshtml", statusCodeName), "~/Views/Error/Index.cshtml", statusCodeName);
        var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = view, ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model) };

        // Return our result
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the first view name that matches the supplied names
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="viewNames">A list of view names</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected string SelectFirstView(ControllerContext context, params string[] viewNames)
    {
        return viewNames.First(view => ViewExists(context, view));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if a view exists
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the view to check</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected bool ViewExists(ControllerContext context, string name)
    {
        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, name, null);

        return result.View != null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the error is **not** an **ApiException** then I route the user to the error controller.
The **ApiException** is just an error that happens when I make an API call from within MVC.
When these errors happen I would like to return the error as JSON back to the client so that the JavaScript can handle it.

I thought not handling the error would do this, but instead it generates a server error (albeit with the JSON error in it) like so:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> {"message":"validateMove validation failure:\r\nThe item is despatched and cannot be moved"}
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: SapphirePlus.Web.ApiException: {"message":"validateMove validation failure:\r\nThe item is despatched and cannot be moved"}
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 181:            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
>
> Line 182:                throw new ApiException(result);

So my question is, can I get the **Application_Error** method to get errors that **ARE** **ApiException**s and return the error as JSON?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to assign your result: `filterContext.Result = result;`

Comment: ah yes, that isn't the issue though, but thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, can I get the Application_Error method to get
>   errors that ARE ApiExceptions and return the error as JSON?

Of course:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var apiException = Server.GetLastError() as ApiException;
    if (apiException != null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();

        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Write("YOUR JSON HERE");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, it just writes the content to the browser and is never picked up by the ajax request.

Comment: Well, then you probably should fix your AJAX request. Since you have provided exactly 0 details about how this request is being made, it is pretty though to be able to help any further with this issue.

Comment: I said it was being made from within MVC, i.e. the call is made from inside the MVC controller to an external API (It seems mad I know, but the device I am using doesn't really support JavaScript). Anyway, I managed to solve this with the filter exception. I will post my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't need to use **Global.asax** at all, I was able to handle it all inside my **ExceptionAttribute** class like this:

```
public class ExceptionAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles any exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current context</param>
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {

        // If our exception has been handled, exit the function
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        // Set our base status code
        var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        // If our exception is an http exception
        if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
        {

            // Cast our exception as an HttpException
            var exception = (HttpException)filterContext.Exception;

            // Get our real status code
            statusCode = exception.GetHttpCode();
        }

        // Set our context result
        var result = CreateActionResult(filterContext, statusCode);

        // Set our handled property to true
        filterContext.Result = result;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creats an action result from the status code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="statusCode">The status code of the error</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ExceptionContext filterContext, int statusCode)
    {

        // Create our context
        var context = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, filterContext.Controller);
        var statusCodeName = ((HttpStatusCode)statusCode).ToString();

        // Create our route
        var controller = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var action = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controller, action);

        // Create our result
        var view = SelectFirstView(context, string.Format("~/Views/Error/{0}.cshtml", statusCodeName), "~/Views/Error/Index.cshtml", statusCodeName);
        var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = view, ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IError>(this.Factorize(model)) };

        // Return our result
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Factorizes the HandleErrorInfo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="error"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual IError Factorize(HandleErrorInfo error)
    {

        // Get the error
        var model = new Error
        {
            Message = "There was an unhandled exception."
        };

        // If we have an error
        if (error != null)
        {

            // Get our exception
            var exception = error.Exception;

            // If we are dealing with an ApiException
            if (exception is ApiException || exception is HttpException)
            {

                // Get our JSON
                var json = JObject.Parse(exception.Message);
                var message = json["exceptionMessage"] != null ? json["exceptionMessage"] : json["message"];

                // If we have a message
                if (message != null)
                {

                    // Update our model message
                    model.Message = message.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {

                // Update our message
                model.Message = exception.Message;
            }
        }

        // Return our response
        return model;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the first view name that matches the supplied names
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="viewNames">A list of view names</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected string SelectFirstView(ControllerContext context, params string[] viewNames)
    {
        return viewNames.First(view => ViewExists(context, view));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if a view exists
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the view to check</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected bool ViewExists(ControllerContext context, string name)
    {
        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, name, null);

        return result.View != null;
    }
}
```

This handled any Mvc error and for my Api calls, I did this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to handle the api response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The HttpResponseMessage</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a string</returns>
    private async Task<string> HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {

        // Read our response content
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // If there was an error, throw an HttpException
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new ApiException(result);

        // Return our result if there are no errors
        return result;
    }
```

This allowed me to capture the **ApiError** and handle the response differently than with any other exception.